# Reshaping a data frame with example

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am trying to reshape my data frame. I have my data in long columns, and I need to spread that data out into the same row but new columns, as you can see above.

One of the main problems I am running into is creating the new columns. I am going to end up creating almost 300 new columns. In my exact problem I am going to have A1, A2, all the way to A23, same with the other variables, so manually initializing the columns does not seem to be feasible.

Is there a way I can loop or maybe make this a function to create columns and reshape my data frame?

```
| Column A | Column B | 
| -------- | -------- | 
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
| Cell 5   | Cell 6   |


| Column A | Column B | Column A1 | Column B1 | Column A2| Column B2|
| -------- | -------- | --------- | --------- | ---------| ---------|
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |  Cell 3   |  Cell 4   | Cell 5   |  Cell 6  |


df$A1 <- NA #Initializing the new column 

df$A1[1] <- df$A[2] #Setting the value in A row 2, to A1 row 1.
```

Comment: Hello Jack. Based on your example, the resulting data frame will have only one row. if your data frame has only one row, how do you plan to analyze it? Most of the data analysis tools in R work with multiple rows per column (variable). If you could provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to do, we can help you reshape the data into an appropriate format.

Comment: @LenGreski I have a huge dataset, and I need to group every 23 rows of about 7 columns. So after the data of the 23 rows gets reassigned to 1 row I need to loop it to do it again and a again. After my entire data set is doing this, I will have enough data to analyze.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicated question and had already given you the solution. ie `df%>%mutate(name = row_number(), .by = playId) %>%pivot_wider(id_cols = playId, values_from = -name)` did you try this code? what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it this way. Main features are creating an `id` column and grouping after pivoting into long format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(name, id), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

```
  `ColA 1` `ColB 1` `ColA 2` `ColB 2` `ColA 3` `ColB 3`
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 Cell 1   Cell 2   Cell 3   Cell 4   Cell 5   Cell 6
```

example data:

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("Cell 1", "Cell 3", "Cell 5"), ColB = c("Cell 2", 
"Cell 4", "Cell 6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Works thank you, now how would I make it so that it after the first set of 23 rows, it stops making new columns and just adds the rows to preexisting columns? for example row 24-47 would be row 2, and 48-71 would be row 3.

Comment: Best is you start a follow-up question with referring to the original question. The black box between OP and the one who answers is sometimes very large!

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple rows after some number of columns are generated we need to establish a row identifier for `pivot_wider()`, which was the basis for my original comment on the OP. To illustrate the concept, we'll create a data frame with a known number of replicates (1 - n) for each column of input data, and use the replicate count to assign a row identifier.

We start by creating 5 replicates for 2 variables, and convert  them to a format where columns are named A 1 - A 5 and B 1 - B 5, where with 50 data elements we wind up with 5 rows of 10 columns after the `pivot_wider()` operation.

First we create some data, where each cell is a unique sequential number so we can see how the data elements are spread across columns.

```
replicate_count <- 5
column_count <- 2
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:(replicate_count * 10),ncol = column_count,byrow = TRUE))
colnames(x) <- c("A","B")
x$var_id <- rep(1:replicate_count,nrow(x) / replicate_count)
x$row_id <- rep(1:replicate_count,each = replicate_count)
```

The first few rows look like this:

```
> head(x)
   A  B var_id row_id
1  1  2      1      1
2  3  4      2      1
3  5  6      3      1
4  7  8      4      1
5  9 10      5      1
6 11 12      1      2
```

Next, we pivot longer to separate the column names from values, combine the column names with the replicate identifiers, and use `row_id` to define the rows.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x %>% pivot_longer(cols = A:B) %>%
     mutate(var_name = paste(name,var_id)) %>% 
     select(var_name,value,row_id) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = var_name,id_cols=row_id)
```

...and the output:

```
  row_id `A 1` `B 1` `A 2` `B 2` `A 3` `B 3` `A 4` `B 4` `A 5` `B 5`
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1      1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
2      2    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
3      3    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
4      4    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
5      5    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50
```

The trick for this solution is the use of the `each =`  argument in the `rep()` function to create `row_id`. Instead of replicating 1:5 5 times, the `each =`  argument allows us to create 5 ones, then 5 twos, etc. This sequencing provides the correct input to use `row_id` as an `id_col` in `pivot_wider()`.

If we move creation of `var_id` and `row_id` into the tidyverse pipeline, the complete solution looks like this:

```
replicate_count <- 5
column_count <- 2
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:(replicate_count * 10),ncol = column_count,byrow = TRUE))
colnames(x) <- c("A","B")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
     mutate(var_id = rep(1:replicate_count,(nrow(x) / replicate_count)),
            row_id = rep(1:replicate_count,each = replicate_count)) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = A:B) %>%
     mutate(var_name = paste(name,var_id)) %>% 
     select(var_name,value,row_id) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = var_name,id_cols=row_id)
```